# How does protein help to cure wound?

Tags: human-biology, proteins, tissue-repair

I understand that the protein helps to repair body tissues. If I increase the intake of protein, would it help to cure the wound more quickly? I would like to know how does the protein reaches the wound and how does it help to heal?

Comment: There are thousands of different proteins in our body, some will make a wound heal, some will not make a difference, some could make the situation even worse, you cannot generalise.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible to know and intake those proteins that heal wound?

Comment: I am just saying that speaking about "the protein" is not meaningful, as there is not just one type of protein. Also, proteins taken through food do not enter the body as such, but are first destroyed to their components (called aminoacids) in the stomach and the intestine. See Armatus answer for example of proteins produced by the body to help wound healing.

Comment: This question seems to be based on some fundamental misunderstanding, there are hundreds of thousands of different proteins. If you're interested in specific aspects of wound healing I recommend you to start with a basic biology textbook first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying protein in general helps to heal wounds is a very far step. Different proteins are essential for nearly every process that happens anywhere in your body.

There is a range of proteins which is required specifically for wound healing. The first step of wound healing is blood clotting in order to close wounds. This uses several so-called clotting factors, all of which are proteins. Some of these help the platelets (small cells in the blood) stick to the walls of the blood vessels which have been damaged, others are responsible for forming a tight clot around them to make sure no more blood leaks out. Most clotting factors also require vitamin K for their production.

The next step is wound healing. This involves several cell types gathering at the wound and laying down what is called connective tissue, a network made mostly of proteins. Cells of the skin will need to replicate themselves in order to close the wound, and they will require lots of proteins for this.

Protein reaches all cells of the body from the intestines via the blood flow.

Eating a diet high in protein would surely not be a bad thing to do - your body needs it everywhere. But it is important that you consume it mixed with healthy amounts of carbohydrate (needed for energy) and fats (needed for many structures and hormones).